# Find the value of |m-n|

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces, vectors

The magnitude of two vectors $m$ and $n$ are 5 and 4 units respectively. The angle between $m$ and $n$ is 60 degrees.

How can I find $|m-n|$?

Comment: Use the dot product or, equivalently, the law of cosines.

Comment: Can you show me some of it ? Thanks

Comment: Ok. Can you imagine (or draw in your mind) a triangle with vectors $\vec{m}$, $\vec{n}$ and $\vec{m}-\vec{n}$ as its sides? One approach is to apply the law of cosines to that triangle.

Comment: The other approach is to recall the fact that for all  vectors $\vec{v}$ we get its length from the equation $|\vec{v}|^2=\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}$. Can you make any headway calculating $(\vec{m}-\vec{n})\cdot(\vec{m}-\vec{n})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector $m-n$ is same as $m+(-n)$ which means addition of n in opposite direction.

Now the angle between them becomes $120°$

Apply the law of vector addition

$\sqrt{m^2+n^2+2mn\cos{120°}}$

Solve it further from here.